# What are positive drive gears?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, automotive-engineering, gears

Gears are called positive gears and belt drives are called negative drives. Explain in detail.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this kind of question should be researched before resorting to any forum for answers.

Comment: Welcome to Engineering! This looks like a [homework question](http://meta.engineering.stackexchange.com/q/121/1832). In order for such questions to be answered in this site, we need you to add details describing the precise problem you're having. What have you tried to solve this yourself? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative drive is an informal expression to describe 'friction drive'. The belt drive is based on friction between the disc and the belt, however positive drive is based on movements without slipping.

Not all belt drive system are 'negative drive'. We also have a positive drive belt system, in this special case, the belt doesn't slip over the driving disc but it rolls over teeth.